# MySQL DATEDIFF based on condition of previous 3 rows

Tags: mysql, sql, case, window-functions, datediff

I'm working on a query that will identify each patient visit as a 'Yes' or 'No' based on whether it is a Readmission. The logic is, if the visit is a psych visit (pat_status LIKE '%IC%' or LIKE '%IY%'), then check the previous 3 visits to see if any are also a psych visit.

If so, find the difference between the current psych visit's admit date and the previous psych visit discharge_date, to see if they came back before 30 days of their last discharge date for psych visit. If these conditions are met, then list 'Y' for 'Readmit' column.

Here is the output table, with a few rows skipped as to not type all of it:

| visit_no | mr_no | admit_date | dischg_date | pat_status | Readmit | Days_between |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7047395 | 508249 | 2019-08-06 | 2019-08-10 | AIM | N | (Null) |
| 7047983 | 508249 | 2019-08-12 | 2019-08-19 | AIC | Nope | 2 |
| 7049597 | 508249 | 2019-08-27 | 2019-08-29 | AIC | Y | 8 |
| 7052596 | 508249 | 2019-08-27 | 2019-10-01 | AIM | N | 30 |
| 7052823 | 508249 | 2019-10-01 | 2019-10-01 | AOE | N | 0 |
| 7054072 | 508249 | 2020-10-16 | 2019-10-22 | AIC | Y | 15 |
| 7055128 | 508249 | 2019-10-29 | 2019-11-01 | AIC | Y | 7 |
| SKIP | SKIP | SKIP | SKIP | SKIP | SKIP | SKIP |
| 7069026 | 508249 | 2020-05-07 | 2020-05-12 | AIC | Y | 10 |
| 7069716 | 508249 | 2020-05-19 | 2020-05-24 | AIY | Y | 7 |
| 7070719 | 508249 | 2020-06-03 | 2020-06-04 | AOE | N | 10 |
| 7072936 | 508249 | 2020-07-02 | 2020-07-09 | AIY | Y | 28 |

I got this output using nested case statements, window function to partition by medical record number ordered by admit_date, and a CTE to filter for a specific mr_no. I got as far as being able to look back 3 rows for '%AIC%' or '%AIY%' using JSON_ARRAYAGG() function, but the last row is where my issue is. It should be listed as 'N' since although there was a previous psych visit in the past 3 rows, the difference is over 30 days between psych visits.

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055). Especially p.p. 5 and 3.

Comment: Why is the visit on 10/16 considered a Readmit? The most recent psych visit prior to that had a discharge date of 8/29, which is more than 30 days ago. Also, I think you're complicating this. Why worry about 3 rows? Is that a requirement? I would be surprised if there's a difference between 3 rows and 100 rows. I would think the only thing that really matters is 30 days.

Answer (score 0):

For each visit to the psych ward we check the last discharge from the psych ward and see if it happened 30 days prior.

```
select   visit_no
        ,mr_no 
        ,admit_date
        ,dischg_date 
        ,pat_status
        ,case when datediff(admit_date, lag(case when grp = 1 then dischg_date end) over(partition by mr_no, grp order by admit_date,dischg_date)) <= 30 then 'Y' else 'N' end as Readmit  
from
(
select   *
        ,case when pat_status like('%IC%') then 1 when pat_status like('%IY%') then 1 end as grp
from     t
) t
order by admit_date, dischg_date
```

| visit_no | mr_no | admit_date | dischg_date | pat_status | Readmit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7047395 | 508249 | 2019-08-06 | 2019-08-10 | AIM | N |
| 7047983 | 508249 | 2019-08-12 | 2019-08-19 | AIC | N |
| 7049597 | 508249 | 2019-08-27 | 2019-08-29 | AIC | Y |
| 7052596 | 508249 | 2019-08-27 | 2019-10-01 | AIM | N |
| 7052823 | 508249 | 2019-10-01 | 2019-10-01 | AOE | N |
| 7055128 | 508249 | 2019-10-29 | 2019-11-01 | AIC | N |
| 7069026 | 508249 | 2020-05-07 | 2020-05-12 | AIC | N |
| 7069716 | 508249 | 2020-05-19 | 2020-05-24 | AIY | Y |
| 7070719 | 508249 | 2020-06-03 | 2020-06-04 | AOE | N |
| 7072936 | 508249 | 2020-07-02 | 2020-07-09 | AIY | N |
| 7054072 | 508249 | 2020-10-16 | 2019-10-22 | AIC | N |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/DfQ2dVl8)